# How I am able to connect (offline) a few times to a Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I am a plugin developer for Bukkit. I played around a year ago with programming on a simple plugin. Now I want to finish it, but I am not able to test many of my functions of my program, because the launcher of Minecraft changed.

I need more players on my server to test some features. But I only have one account with a original Minecraft.

Of curse I am able to login in with it, but only one time. Earlier I was able to change the name of the Launcher if I am playing offline. Now this is not working anymore...

To be able to log in Multiplie times on my server I have to change the name of the player so the server is able to identify diffrent players.

- Minecraft Version: 1.7.5
- Launcher Version: 1.3.11
- OS: Windows 8.1
- Bukkit Server Version: 1.7.5-R0.1

Comment: So do you want multiple minecraft windows? Or multiple nicknames?

Comment: I want multiple minecraft windows, but in every window I need a diffrent name because if it is the same name I can't log in at the same server!

Comment: Edited my comment.  I now understand what you're looking for but unfortunately I don't have an answer.

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to log in to multiple accounts? If so, ask your friends/family if you could borrow their accounts, to use as alts. than you just have to make sure that you connect to the server in each of the windows you open before opening a new one.

Comment: @joeybab3 Kinda I want to log in multipe times. But not with original account. If I would use original accounts I need the account name and the account password. Sure I could at least one of my friends to use his account but one is not enough. As I descriped I have one original account (my account) and want to use the offline mode function to login multiple times on my server. Means I need diffrent names because it is so to say my ID and I only can login one time with one ID!

Comment: ok, thanks for elaborating, kust as @mkalafut said, i dont have an answer than

Comment: Can't you just plug in a different name into the launcher and run offline? Offline mode doesn't do the authentication-dance with Mojang so it should just "work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Only follow the below instructions if you agree to use them for legal purposes only (like the one described in the question).*

After some experimenting, I managed to find a way to do what you want. One thing I found out, though, is that you need a separate Minecraft installation for each instance of Minecraft you want running concurrently.

## Method

#### Getting and running the launcher

1. I altered and repackaged the [Portableapps.com Minecraft Portable](http://portableapps.com/node/30573) launcher, which you should download [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6ecx7uwa79cjh9/MinecraftPortable.zip).
2. Extract the newly downloaded archive to the directory of your choice.
3. Run the launcher (called `MinecraftPortable.exe`) from the folder you extracted the archive in, enter your credentials, and let it download the latest version of Minecraft. After it has finished downloading, and you are at the main menu, exit Minecraft.

#### Changing your username

1. Make sure you are in the extracted folder where you ran the Minecraft launcher from.
2. Open the file `launcher_profiles.json` in the `Data>.minecraft` folder with your favorite text-editor. Find line 16, and replace your original Minecraft username with the one you would like to change it to (inside the double-quotes after `"displayName":`). For example, it could look like `"displayName": "PlayerOne"`.
3. Now is the time to disable your internet connection. You will not be able to play Minecraft with your changed username if do not disable it.
4. The next time you start Minecraft, you should be able to play it with the username you set.

**Please note:** Each time you start Minecraft with the username changed, you will need to make sure your internet connection is disabled. Otherwise it will reset to your original username.

#### Running multiple instances

As I explained at the start of this answer, you need to have a separate Minecraft installation for each instance of Minecraft you want to run simultaneously. This is one way you can do that:

1. Create a duplicate of the folder you extracted in step two.
2. Rename two files. You will need to rename `MinecraftPortable.exe` to something different like `MinecraftPortable2.exe`, and give `App>AppInfo>Launcher>MinecraftPortable.ini` the same file name, which in this case is `MinecraftPortable2.ini`.
3. Now all you need to do is follow the instructions under the heading *Changing your username* again, and you will be able to have two instances of Minecraft connected to the same server.

## Result

[image]

If you want to use these simultaneous Minecraft instances to join a server, you need to make sure that in the `server.properties` file on the server, it has `online-mode=false`. This step works on both vanilla and bukkit servers. If you skip this step, though, the server will not let you join it.